# ContentScript not injected in file scheme

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, manifest, google-chrome-app

I have used following setting in my manifest.json file

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "My Cool Extension",
  "version": "0.1",
   "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
  "permissions": [
  "tabs", "<all_urls>"
],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": ["content.js"], 
      "all_frames": true,
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ]
}
```

But the strange thing is that content.js in not getting injected in URLS like `file:///D:/IDTECH%20new%20device/Augusta%20Chrome%20View/window%20-%20Copy.html` i.e. If I open *.html file directly.

when I click on "Allow access to file URLs" checkbox, both of the checkbox hides. and my extension stop working. I have to re-install my extension then :(
[image]

Comment: The second part of your question looks like a bug. I've updated my answer, you should file on https://crbug.com

Comment: @rgthree It looks like a security feature, not a bug.

Comment: @Xan While that may be the case, it's still a UI bug worth filing on crbug.com to at least remove/disable the checkbox if it's only going to break the interface. (Could have sworn I responded to you in the answer's comments below, sorry).

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that you have not authorized your extension to run on the `file` scheme?

> Note: Access to file URLs isn't automatic. The user must visit the extensions management page and opt in to file access for each extension that requests it.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns

Visit your `chrome://extensions/` page in your browser, and check the box for your extension. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

---

**Part 2**  Okay, now that we've solved the initial question, it looks like your second part (of your extension freezing when you check the box) is a bug in Chrome. You should look for an existing issue and, if there is none, file a new one at https://crbug.com.

Note, I was able to check the box for an unpackaged extension and it works just fine, so you should still be able to develop fine, and release to the Chrome store fine. The bug seems to only be for a CRX that is installed manually. *It's also possible these are considered "unsafe" and are not meant to have access to file scheme, but it's odd the checkbox is there and there's at least no message that that could be the case..*

Comment: Okay one more weird thing, when I click on "Allow access to file URLs" checkbox, both of the checkbox hides. also check my edited question again for image :)

Comment: Does it also happen with the unpacked extension? It's possible that Chrome denies this for "untrusted" packed extensions.

Comment: @WaqarAhmed I just tested it with a simple extension, unpackaged and it's working fine for me. Perhaps something else is wrong with your extension? I am using the dev channel of Chrome, it's possible there's a bug in the release version, though I doubt that's whats wrong.

Comment: @Xan Yup, just tested it on my own with a simple extension.

Comment: @rgthree Try to pack your test extension, and then install the CRX by dragging it onto the extensions page. OP's screenshot ("Not from Chrome Web Store") indicates this route.